# Socket connection to postgres is not close when network down or hard boot the server

Tags: python, sockets, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I am creating connection with postgresql using sqlalchemy and executing simple command.

```
>>> from sqlalchemy import create_engine
>>> c = create_engine('postgres://myuser@myremoteserver/mydb?keepalives_idle=4&keepalives_interval=1&keepalives_count=5')
>>> c.execute('select 1').scalar()
1
```

Its working fine.

After creating connection when you execute query it will create socket to the postgres server in this example it will create socket to `myremoteserver`. We can check the socket with unix `ss` command. (You can also use `netstat`).

```
[root@myclient ~]# ss -torp | grep python
ESTAB      0      0            192.168.1.15:43471       myremoteserver:postgres  timer:(keepalive,1.319ms,0) users:(("python",4074,3))
```

If the network went down or postgres server machine crash after creating connection.

```
>>> c = create_engine('postgres://myuser@myremoteserver/mydb?keepalives_idle=4&keepalives_interval=1&keepalives_count=5')
```

(You can do `ifdown eth0` on `myremoteserver` for network down)

Then it will close the connection after 5 attempts to the server.

```
[root@myclient ~]# ss -torp | grep python
ESTAB      0      0            192.168.1.15:43471       myremoteserver:postgres  timer:(keepalive,1.319ms,0) users:(("python",4074,3))
[root@myclient ~]# ss -torp | grep python
ESTAB      0      0            192.168.1.15:43471       myremoteserver:postgres  timer:(keepalive,738ms,0) users:(("python",4074,3))
[root@myclient ~]# ss -torp | grep python
ESTAB      0      0            192.168.1.15:43471       myremoteserver:postgres  timer:(keepalive,2.720ms,0) users:(("python",4074,3))
[root@myclient ~]# ss -torp | grep python
ESTAB      0      0            192.168.1.15:43471       myremoteserver:postgres  timer:(keepalive,788ms,2) users:(("python",4074,3))
[root@myclient ~]# ss -torp | grep python
ESTAB      0      0            192.168.1.15:43471       myremoteserver:postgres  timer:(keepalive,191ms,4) users:(("python",4074,3))
[root@myclient ~]# ss -torp | grep python
[root@myclient ~]# ss -torp | grep python
```

This is the behavior of the connection which we set in connection string.

Problem occurs if we execute query before socket close and server down.

```
# do ifdown eth0 on postgres server to break the network connection.
# execute query before socket close.
>>> c.execute('select 1').scalar()
```

Now if you check socket then

```
[root@myclient ~]# ss -torp | grep python
ESTAB      0      74           192.168.1.15:43471       myremoteserver:postgres  timer:(on,1.602ms,3) users:(("python",3098,7))
[root@myclient ~]# ss -torp | grep python
ESTAB      0      74           192.168.1.15:43471       myremoteserver:postgres  timer:(on,585ms,3) users:(("python",3098,7))
[root@myclient ~]# ss -torp | grep python
ESTAB      0      74           192.168.1.15:43471       myremoteserver:postgres  timer:(on,2.833ms,4) users:(("python",3098,7))
[root@myclient ~]# ss -torp | grep python
ESTAB      0      74           192.168.1.15:43471       myremoteserver:postgres  timer:(on,1.851ms,4) users:(("python",3098,7))
[root@myclient ~]# ss -torp | grep python
ESTAB      0      74           192.168.1.15:43471       myremoteserver:postgres  timer:(on,808ms,4) users:(("python",3098,7))
[root@myclient ~]# ss -torp | grep python
ESTAB      0      74           192.168.1.15:43471       myremoteserver:postgres  timer:(on,5.393ms,5) users:(("python",3098,7))
[root@myclient ~]# ss -torp | grep python
ESTAB      0      74           192.168.1.15:43471       myremoteserver:postgres  timer:(on,3.846ms,5) users:(("python",3098,7))
.................
.................
.................
[root@myclient ~]# ss -torp | grep python
ESTAB      0      74           192.168.1.15:43471       myremoteserver:postgres  timer:(on,5.268ms,72) users:(("python",3098,7))
[root@myclient ~]# ss -torp | grep python
ESTAB      0      74           192.168.1.15:43471       myremoteserver:postgres  timer:(on,4.804ms,254) users:(("python",3098,7))
```

As per connection string socket must be close after 5 attempts. But I don't know whey its trying more then 5 times and reach to 254 attempts.

What I have to set to close the socket after 5 attempts even if we execute query between server crash and socket close from client.

**Note : keepalives_idle, keepalives_interval and keepalives_count is use to set the keepalive parameter in TCP connection.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PostgreSQL docs:

> Controls the number of TCP keepalives that can be lost before the client's connection to the server is considered dead. A value of zero uses the system default. This parameter is ignored for connections made via a Unix-domain socket, or if keepalives are disabled. It is only supported on systems where the TCP_KEEPCNT socket option is available; on other systems, it has no effect.

In other words. if your system doesn't support it, it has no effect and normal timeout rules will apply.